# Integration by parts, any help?

Tags: calculus

How may I calculate Integration by parts for the following multivariable function?

$$I_n(x)=\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n}f(t)dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can write out the formula for you, I guess, assuming that $F' =f$ exists:
$$
\int_a^x (x-t)^n f(t)dt = \int_a^x (x-t)^n dF(t)t = [(x-t)^n F(t)]_a^x + \int_a^x n(x-t)^{n-1} F(t) dt
$$
so that
$$
\int_a^x (x-t)^n f(t)dt = -(x-a)^n F(a) + \int_a^x n(x-t)^{n-1} F(t) dt
$$
Is that what you are looking for? Does $f$ have any other properties, like those of a CDF, for example?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to replace ∫(−)−1() with something like $I_n$ or $I_{n+1}$ (with some edits of course). **I know that f(t) is continuous**