# Finding derivative of integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How may I calculate derivative for the following function?

$$I_n(x)=\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n}f(t)dt$$

**Note**: I'm given that $f$ is continuous

Comment: With respect to $x$?

Comment: What do you know about the Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: $$I_n(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}x^k\int_a^xt^{n-k}f(t){\rm d}t.$$ Can you use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to conclude now?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Sorry I don't know it and therefore can't use it, I'm looking for a solution using Leibniz integral rule, since I know it will help here but can't implement it :-(

Comment: @Daniel98: I suggested FTC because that's the more "basic" rule. If you do know the Leibniz rule, then I'm not sure why you're struggling. I suggest that you edit your question and show us where you got stuck upon applying the rule. (Even if you have no idea, just tell us what *you* think is the Leibniz rule and why you are not able to apply it.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I will try to explain here since writing it will take hours (It's hard to write math here) So when I calculated it I find that there is no f() in my expression which shouldn't be the case

Comment: Your [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726414/integration-by-parts-any-help) is about using integration by parts on the same function. Do you have a specific reason why you want to find the derivative of $I_n(x)$? Could you update your question with additional context?

Comment: @Axion004 I'm trying to solve a bigger problem and won't want to make this too complex so I'm asking on this function

Comment: @Daniel98: Since I couldn't understand what you did to end up with no $f$ from your comment, I have added an answer. Let me know in the comments there what you have a problem with and I will update it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

$$I_n(x)=\int_{a}^{x} (x-t)^{n}f(t){\rm d}t \\ \text{Leibniz rule is-} \\ \dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t) {\rm d}t\right) = f(x,b(x))\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}b(x) - f(x,a(x)\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) {\rm d}t \\ \dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}I_n(x) = (x-x)^nf(x)\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}x - (x-a)^nf(a)\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}a + \int_a^xn(x-t)^{n-1}f(t){\rm d}t \\ = nI_{n-1}(x)$$

Comment: One mistake at the end, it's $I_n$ not $I_{n-1}$

Comment: After taking the partial derivative of $(x-t)^nf(t)$, it became $n(x-t)^{n-1}f(t)$ so there is $n-1$ in the power so it's basically $I_{n-1}$ tell me if you still think there is a mistake

Answer (score 2):

Leibniz's rule tells the following:

$$\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x, t){\rm d}t\right) = f(x, b(x))b'(x) - f(x, a(x))a'(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x, t)\right){\rm d}t.$$

---

1. Do you see what $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $f(x, t)$ will be in this case?
2. With which of the three terms on the right do you have a problem calculating?

Comment: How we could know what it x and what is t? I could choose anything... and what if I have 3 variables

Comment: Doesn't your question already involve $x$ and $t$? You wish to differentiate $I_n(x)$. Can you try to "match" the appropriate terms? In the case of $I_n(x)$, what appears in the position of $a(x)$?

Comment: @Daniel98 the $x$ is the variable wrt which you are taking the derivative